# Configuring Hadoop, HBase and Hive Cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive, apache-zookeeper

I am a newbie to Hadoop, HBase and Hive. I installed Hadoop, HBase and Hive in pseudodistributed mode and everything works fine.
Now I am planning to set up an simple Hadoop Cluster (5 nodes) with Hive, HBase and ZooKeeper. I´ve read several documentations and instructions before but i could not find a good explanation for my question. I´m not sure, where to run all the daemons. This is my consideration:

**Node_1** (Master)

- NameNode
- JobTrakcer
- HBase Master
- ZooKeeper (Standalone node; managed by HBase)

**Node_2** (Backup_Master)

- SecondaryNameNode

**Node_3** (Slave1)

- DataNode1
- TaskTracker1
- RegionServer1

**Node_4** (Slave2)

- DataNode2
- TaskTracker2
- RegionServer2

**Node_5** (Slave3)

- DataNode3
- TaskTracker3
- RegionServer3

I know, in production it is recommended to run ZooKeeper ensemble at an odd number of nodes (seperate Cluster). But for a simple cluster, is it OK to set up a standalone ZooKeeper node which runs on the master node?

Another question is regarding Hive: I know that Hive is a Hadoop client. Should I also install Hive on the master node? Does it make sense?

Thanks for all tips and comments!
Hakan

Note: I have just 5 machines to simulate a cluster.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but I wanted to point out to you that SecondaryNameNode is *not* a backup NameNode. It's a common mistake to make, but that is not SecondaryNameNode's purpose. You should look into having a passive/active NameNode if you want to simply have a back up. Source: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#What_is_the_purpose_of_the_secondary_name-node.3F

Comment: Thanks for your tip Eric!  
**Is there nobody else to help me regarding my problem?? It´s really urgent..**

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, I believe you can setup Zookeeper on the master node; I did install all of them on the same server.

What I do not understand from your question why you installed hadoop in pseudo distributed mode if you have 5 machines in your cluster? it might be better to install a fully distributed mode.

For hive, it seems that you have to install it with hadoop

```
Hive uses hadoop that means:

you must have hadoop in your path OR export HADOOP_HOME=<hadoop-install-dir>
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! No, installed Hadoop and all the other Projects on one Machine (local) in pseudo distributed mode first and it works fine. NOW i am planning to install hadoop in fully distributed mode with 5 machines. Therefore my question on wich Machines to start all the daemons.. What does that mean, to install hive with hadoop? Hive is a Cient of Hadoop.. Does it not make sense to install Hive also on the first Node (Master)?

Comment: Yes, I have historically installed Hive on equivalent of your first node.

Answer (score 0):

> For hive, it seems that you have to install it with hadoop
>   Hive uses hadoop that means:
>   you must have hadoop in your path OR export HADOOP_HOME=

@iTech : That´s right. If you install hive, you have to set the variable "HADOOP_HOME" to your hadoop installation path.But that´s not the problem..As I said, I worked before with Hadoop and Hive in pseudo distributed mode.

The only problem is, I´m not sure where to run the all the daemons in a 5-node-cluster in fully distributed mode. I´m confused because I want to run a lot of Tools together (Hadoop, HBase and Hive)

Hope that someone have a good tip...

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use the described cluster for testing purposes, it is OK to have all your master nodes on the same server. Also you can move the  SecondaryNameNode role to Node_1, since SecondaryNameNode is not a backup server for the NameNode, it is there to [make checkpoints of your NameNode](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Secondary_NameNode). So it makes sense to use the Node_2 as another "worker" node in you cluster, or the HiveServer2 and the metastore.

Hope this will help.